# Find the occurence based on the index values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have a table like follows, considering the presence of nan:

```
    A       B       C       D
0   4.0     85.0    85.0    2.0
1   34.0    89.0    89.0    7.0
2   100     99.0    99.0    10.0
3   148.0   100.0   100.0   27.0
4   nan     103.0   nan     30.0
```

What I want it to get the all unique numbers from the Table, for which I have used

```
itertools.chain(*[df[j].unique().tolist() for j in df.columns])
```

that would give me all the unique values across the `df`. Now the real problem is that I want to have output something like follows:

```
id  A  B  C  D
2   0  0  0  1
4   1  0  0  0
7   0  0  0  1
10  0  0  0  1
27  0  0  0  1
30  0  0  0  1
34  1  0  0  0
...
85  0  1  1  0
89  0  1  1  0
100 1  1  1  0
```

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), get `maximal` values per second level, rename columns names for cast to integers and last transpose:

```
df = pd.get_dummies(df.stack()).max(level=1).rename(columns=int).T
print (df)
     A  B  C  D
2    0  0  0  1
4    1  0  0  0
7    0  0  0  1
10   0  0  0  1
27   0  0  0  1
30   0  0  0  1
34   1  0  0  0
85   0  1  1  0
89   0  1  1  0
99   0  1  1  0
100  1  1  1  0
103  0  1  0  0
148  1  0  0  0
```

Comment: `.rename(columns=int)` is neat :)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with **`keep=False`**:

```
s=df.stack()
new_df = (pd.concat([s, s.duplicated(keep=False)],axis=1)
            .set_index(0,append=True)[1]
            .unstack(1, fill_value=False)
            .droplevel(None)
            .astype(int))
```

We can also use `melt` + `pivot_table`

```
df2 = df.melt()
new_df = (df2.assign(dup=df2['value'].duplicated(keep=False))
             .pivot_table(index='value',
                          columns='variable',
                          values='dup',
                          fill_value=False)
             .astype(int))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also implemented with following that also solve the purpose.

```
pd.get_dummies(df.melt()).dropna(how='any')\
            .groupby('value').sum()
```